# How are the Human Rights Data Analysis Group (HRDAG) data delimited?

Tags: csv

I am trying to read an HRDAG dataset into R. ([here is a link to the dataset](https://hrdag.org/content/sierraleone/SL-TRC-data.csv)). I don't understand how the columns are separated, and was wondering if there is a particular argument I need to specify in order to correctly read the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a tab-delimited file. You can read it in with the the [readr](https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/read_delim.html) package. For instance:

```
readr::read_delim( '/Path-to-Folder/SL-TRC-data.csv', delim = '\t')
```